# Can't $Diff an Intersection type

Tags: flowtype

I ran into an issue where an intersection type wouldn't work with `$Diff`. I ran into this when trying to implement a react HOC for a component that had an intersection prop.

A simplified example looks like:

```
type One = { one: number }
type Two = { two: number }
type Three = { three: number }
type Both = One & Two
type All = Both & Three

const both:$Diff<All, Three> = { one: 1, two: 2 }
           ^ Cannot instantiate `$Diff` because undefined property `three` [1] is incompatible with number [2].
References:
6: type Both = One & Two
               ^ [1]
5: type Three = { three: number }
                         ^ [2]
```

If there is a way to correct this, I use `One` and `Both` as prop typings for components, and `All` and `$Diff` is part of the HOC typing.

Thanks!

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagPIDtsBeUAb1FgIC5Q8BXAWwCNMAnUAXxQ2wBV5ZQxMsn7U6TVhy5ZQPABYtMRUqGQKlYhszac0MgEKw1g3AVAAyWf2nYAgtGgnDxy-MWZEiAMYUAzslBGIzlKABIAEQBLSEgAHntoABpZdUwAPhMyCkxqAEZkkVhqACYOIA

Answer (score 1):

I feel there are some weaknesses in the way flow handles intersection types, compounding them should work but doesn't as expected.

If you can define `All` as the intersection of `One`, `Two`, and `Three`, it will work as expected.

`$Shape<>` can sometimes get you around this sort of problem but I couldn't get it to play on this occasion.

```
// @flow
type One = { one: number }
type Two = { two: number }
type Three = { three: number }
type Both = One & Two
type All = One & Two & Three

const both:$Diff<All, Three> = { one: 1, two: 2 }
```